# Rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the previous line

Tags: python, file, seek

I am doing text processing and using 'readline()' function as follows:

```
ifd = open(...)
for line in ifd:
   while (condition)
         do something...
         line = ifd.readline()
         condition = ....
```

#Here when the condition becomes false I need to rewind the pointer so that the 'for' loop read the same line again.

ifd.fseek() followed by readline is giving me a '\n' character. How to rewind the pointer so that the whole line is read again.

```
>>> ifd.seek(-1,1)
>>> line = ifd.readline()
>>> line
'\n'
```

#### Here is my code

```
labtestnames = sorted(tmp)
#Now read each line in the inFile and write into outFile
ifd = open(inFile, "r")
ofd = open(outFile, "w")
#read the header
header = ifd.readline() #Do nothing with this line. Skip
#Write header into the output file
nl = "mrn\tspecimen_id\tlab_number\tlogin_dt\tfluid"
offset = len(nl.split("\t"))
nl = nl + "\t" + "\t".join(labtestnames)
ofd.write(nl+"\n")
lenFields = len(nl.split("\t"))


print "Reading the input file and converting into modified file for further processing (correlation analysis etc..)"

prevTup = (0,0,0)
rowComplete = 0
k=0
for line in ifd:
    k=k+1
    if (k==200): break

    items = line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
    if((items[0] =='')):
        continue
    newline= list('' for i in range(lenFields))
    newline[0],newline[1],newline[3],newline[2],newline[4] = items[0], items[1], items[3], items[2], items[4]
    ltests = []
    ltvals = []
    while(cmp(prevTup, (items[0], items[1], items[3])) == 0): # If the same mrn, lab_number and specimen_id then fill the same row. else create a new row.
        ltests.append(items[6])
        ltvals.append(items[7])
        pos = ifd.tell()
        line = ifd.readline()
        prevTup = (items[0], items[1], items[3])
        items = line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        rowComplete = 1

    if (rowComplete == 1): #If the row is completed, prepare newline and write into outfile
        indices = [labtestnames.index(x) for x in ltests]
        j=0
        ifd.seek(pos)
        for i in indices:
            newline[i+offset] = ltvals[j]
            j=j+1

    if (rowComplete == 0): # 
        currTup = (items[0], items[1], items[3])
        ltests = items[6]
        ltvals = items[7]
        pos = ifd.tell()
        line = ifd.readline()
        items = line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        newTup = (items[0], items[1], items[3])
        if(cmp(currTup, newTup) == 0):
            prevTup = currTup
            ifd.seek(pos)
            continue
        else:
            indices = labtestnames.index(ltests)
            newline[indices+offset] = ltvals

    ofd.write(newline+"\n")
```

Comment: `ifd.seek(-1,1)` moves the read position one byte back relative to the current position, which will usually be a '\n' after a `readline`.

Comment: Curious, is the file huge, or can you read the file into memory? If you can read it into memory, I see a simple solution....

Comment: @unutbu the file is almost 20 GB in size and I can' read all in memory. I updated my previous post for sample input and output file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be handled more simply using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). `groupby` can cluster all the contiguous lines that deal with the same mrn, specimen_id, and lab_num.

The code that does this is

```
for key, group in IT.groupby(reader, key = mykey):
```

where `reader` iterates over the lines of the input file, and `mykey` is defined by

```
def mykey(row):
    return (row['mrn'], row['specimen_id'], row['lab_num'])
```

Each row from `reader` is passed to `mykey`, and all rows with the same key are clustered together in the same `group`.

---

While we're at it, we might as well use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read each line into a dict (which I call `row`). This frees us from having to deal with low-level string manipulation like `line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")` and instead of referring to columns by index numbers (e.g. `row[3]`) we can write code that speaks in higher-level terms such as `row['lab_num']`.

---

```
import itertools as IT
import csv

inFile = 'curious.dat'
outFile = 'curious.out'

def mykey(row):
    return (row['mrn'], row['specimen_id'], row['lab_num'])

fieldnames = 'mrn specimen_id date    lab_num Bilirubin   Lipase  Calcium Magnesium   Phosphate'.split()

with open(inFile, 'rb') as ifd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(ifd, delimiter = '\t')
    with open(outFile, 'wb') as ofd:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(
            ofd, fieldnames, delimiter = '\t', lineterminator = '\n', )
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, group in IT.groupby(reader, key = mykey):
            new = {}
            row = next(group)
            for key in ('mrn', 'specimen_id', 'date', 'lab_num'):
                new[key] = row[key]
                new[row['labtest']] = row['result_val']                
            for row in group:
                new[row['labtest']] = row['result_val']
            writer.writerow(new)
```

yields

```
mrn specimen_id date    lab_num Bilirubin   Lipase  Calcium Magnesium   Phosphate
4419529 1614487 26.2675 5802791G    0.1             
3319529 1614487 26.2675 5802791G    0.3 153 8.1 2.1 4
5713871 682571  56.0779 9732266E                    4.1
```

Comment: Does this really work? Some sources claim that it's a bad idea to mix iterating over a file and the `readline` method.

Comment: @user4815162342: Yes, it works. Perhaps you are thinking of iterating over the
file with `for line in ifd` and calling `ifd.readline()`? The loop `for line in ifd`
pre-reads lines and stores them in a buffer. `readline` does not read that buffer,
so mixing iteration and read methods would lose data (were it not for Python thankfully raising a ValueError). But we are not using the
`for line in ifd` loop here, so all is well.

Comment: As @user4815162342 pointed, I am getting ValueError for mixing iteration and read methods. I included my original code of in the main post

Comment: Replace `for line in ifd` with `for line in ifd.xreadlines()`, and everything will work just fine.

Comment: @unutbu, Thanks. It is working for small file. As I said my file is approximately 20 GB in size, and not sure if the above code will work on such a large file.

Comment: Curious, best to try it, though I think it will. `itertools.groupby` and `csv.DictReader` do not try to load the whole file into memory.

Comment: @unutbu, I am trying to understand the above code but confused why u used new[row['labtest']] = row['result_val']  twice.

Comment: A group may contain only one row. In that case `row = next(group)` will consume the `group` iterator, and the `for row in group:` suite will be passed over. So `new[row['labtest']] = row['result_val']` is used in two places to make sure every row gets processed. Think of the first loop, `for key in ('mrn', 'specimen_id', 'date', 'lab_num'):` as only handling the first row, and `for row in group` as handling all other rows -- if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a perfect use case for [yield expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions). Consider the following example that prints lines from a file, repeating some of them at random:

```
def buflines(fp):
    r = None
    while True:
        r = yield r or next(fp)
        if r:
            yield None

from random import randint

with open('filename') as fp:
    buf = buflines(fp)
    for line in buf:
        print line
        if randint(1, 100) > 80:
            print 'ONCE AGAIN::'
            buf.send(line)
```

Basically, if you want to process an item once again, you `send` it back to the generator. On the next iteration you will be reading the same item once again.